# Increment folders names numbering using windows command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, powershell-2.0

Every week I create a new folder and, to keep them in order, I name them with a numbering like `01 - day-month`, `02 - day-month`, etc. I have already created the windows cmd script that names the folders according to the date, but now I would like to write the part of the script that puts the number of the folder before the date (keeping the number dashed with a 0).

I have already seen an example here on stackexchange but could not fully understand the code.

This is what I have got so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "baseName= - "
set "n=0"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri "[0-9]*%baseName%*"'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
  if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
md "%n%%baseName%"
```

PowerShell 2.0 is welcome as well.

Comment: If your locale week definition (1st day of week/1st week of year) matches  with ISO8601 you can use `DateToWeek` sub/function from [Ritchie Lawrence batch function library](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/)

Comment: In your case above, `dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."` lists directories within the current directory whose name begins with _<space><dash><space>_ and ends with _<dot>_. I'd suggest you try `DIR/B/AD-S-L "*%baseName%*` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "baseName= - "
set "n=0"
for /f "delims= " %%F in (
  '2^>nul dir /b /ad "*%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri /c:"[0-9][0-9]%baseName%.*"'
) do (
  if %%F gtr !n! set "n=%%F"
)
IF %n%==0 (SET /a n=100) ELSE (SET "n=1%n%")
set /a n+=1
echo md "%n:~-2%%baseName%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Quite a few changes, which I will explain.

First, the `dir` command outputs the directory list in `/b` (basic) form of `/ad` directorynames. As @compo said, you need `*%basename%*` because your directoryname will be of the form `nn - something`, not starting with`%basename%`. The `2^>nul` directs that any error report from `dir` (such as `no files found`) is suppressed.

The output of this command is then *piped* to `findstr` which selects lines that `/xri` e**x**actly, case-**I**nsensitively match the **R**egular expression provided.

The original `regex`, "[0-9]*%baseName%*" is not adequate. It attempts to say "any number of leading digits (including no leading digits at all)" followed by the string in `basename` followed by `*` which would mean "any number of the last character in `basename`"

Furthermore, since `basename` contains <kbd>Space</kbd>, findstr treats each space-separated substring as a separate string to find, and would therefore attempt to find and exact match to "any number of digits" OR "-" OR "*", so it's not surprising it yielded no results.

The replacement `regex` first is preceded by `/c:` which means "spaces are ordinary characters" the regex itself then specifies two leading digits, the `basename` string and `.*` - any number of any other character (since your directorynames-to-be-examined will have been renamed to `02 - day-month`).

By setting up `delims` as a space, the (implicit default single token) assigned to `%%F` will be any characters in the directoryname in the list (after `findstr` has filtered it) up to but not including the first <kbd>Space</kbd>

So, all that's left to do now is to find the highest numeric value in `%%F`. This is done by comparing `%%F` to the value of `n` (in future, please use meaningful names) and setting `n` to the value of `%%F` if *that* is greater.

the `!n!` syntax is required because of the `delayed expansion` characteristic (there are many, many SO articles about this - use the `search` in the top bar to find a few). Essentially, within a code-block (parenthesised series of commands) any `%var%` is replaced by the value of the variable at the time the block is encountered and `!var!` (with `delayedexpansion` invoked) is the run-time value (the value as it changes through operation of the block)

Once theloop is finished, we have one of two situations: Either there were no matches (so `n` will have the value `0`) or there were matches so `n` will have a value of `nn`, which will be 2 digits)

`set /a` increments the value in `n`, which is all fine and good - *EXCEPT* that if `n` happens to be `08` or `09`, the operation will fail because `cmd` sees a digit-string starting `0` as *octal* and `8` and `9` are not valid octal characters.

The standard workaround for this problem is to string a `1` before the two-digit value. Obviously, had `n` been `0` then adding `1` to it would make `1` - and you require a leading zero, so in that case, set `n` to `100`. (I used a forced-arithmetic `set`)

Having incremented the number, the `md` now needs the last 2 characters of `n`, so that's the meaning of `%n:~-2%`. I've just `echo`ed the proposed new name, just in case of a problem. Simply remove the `echo` keyword after you've tested to activate the `md`.

And it's best to cut-and-paste solutions as batch can exhibit odd syntax-sensitivity. It also avoids tyops.

Comment: I like the idea behind `IF %n%==0 (SET /a n=100) ELSE (SET "n=1%n%")` to avoid octal interpretation of the numbers although it would be even better to use `set "n=00"` above and just `set "n=1%n%"` after __FOR__ loop. And __DIR__ option `/b` means __bare__ and not *basic* to be 100% precise. So +1 by me for this very good explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution which uses a different approach which is fast with the exception of execution of **WMIC** command which can't be avoided when current day and month should be determined from local date/time in a region and language independent way. Reformatting the string of environment variable **DATE** would be faster, but the format of this date string depends on Windows region settings as defined for the used user account.

The batch code with lots of comment lines (lines starting with command **REM**):

```
@echo off
goto GetFolderList

rem Run DIR to get a list of only folder names because of /AD and /B
rem matching the wildcard pattern ?? - ??-?? ordered reverse by name
rem because of /O-N with suppressing the error message DIR outputs if
rem no such folder can be found in current directory by redirecting
rem the error message to device NUL.

rem From folder name just the first two characters are assigned to loop
rem variable I as the default delimiters space/tab are used on splitting
rem up the folder name into tokens. Only the first token is processed by
rem outer FOR with the default options, i.e. the number to increment.

rem The inner FOR executes the SET command only if the first space/tab
rem delimited string of current folder name from DIR output contains any
rem non digit character. So if environment variable Number is defined
rem after inner FOR loop execution, the folder name is not valid as it
rem does not start with a number with 2 digits.

rem On current folder name not starting with a number, the outer FOR loop
rem is processed further with next folder name. Otherwise the number of
rem the current folder name being automatically the highest number because
rem of using leading zeros and reverse output by name is assigned to the
rem environment variable Number and outer FOR loop is exited with a jump
rem to label TrimNumber.

rem The numbering for first folder starts with 01 in case of no (valid)
rem folder matching wildcard pattern ?? - ??-?? is found in current folder.

:GetFolderList
set "Number="
for /F %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N "?? - ??-??" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "delims=0123456789" %%J in ("%%I") do set "Number=none"
    if defined Number (
        set "Number="
    ) else (
        set Number=%%I
        goto TrimNumber
    )
)
set "Number=01"
goto CreateFolder


rem On incrementing a number with leading zeros using an arithmetic expression
rem it can happen easily that the number is interpreted octal, especially if
rem the number would have 3 digits which is not the case here. So it is better
rem to remove the leading zero(s) before incrementing the number by 1.

rem Of course with number from folder name being 00 it happens on removing
rem in a loop the first character from string when being 0 that the number
rem string is suddenly not defined anymore which must result also in an
rem exit of this loop trimming leading zeros.

:TrimNumber
if not "%Number:~0,1%" == "0" goto IncrementNumber
set "Number=%Number:~1%"
if defined Number goto TrimNumber
set "Number=01"
goto CreateFolder


rem After leading zeros are removed it is safe to increment the number by 1.
rem Then it is necessary to make sure that the number has always two digits
rem even on being 1 to 9. This can be achieved by inserting a leading 0 on
rem number string and then get just the last 2 characters from number string.

:IncrementNumber
set /A Number+=1
set "Number=0%Number%"
set "Number=%Number:~-2%"
goto CreateFolder


rem The WMIC command below with used options outputs among blank
rem lines in UTF-16 Little Endian encoding also a line with

rem LocalDateTime=20170617192138.218000+120

rem Of interest from this line is the string after the equal sign as it
rem contains year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond and UTC
rem offset of configured time zone in fixed and region independent format.

rem From this date/time string just the month and day is needed for the
rem folder name in format DD-MM with incremented number being prepended.

:CreateFolder
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDateTime=%%I"
set "FolderName=%Number% - %LocalDateTime:~6,2%-%LocalDateTime:~4,2%"
md "%FolderName%"
```

**Edit:** The method to avoid octal interpretation of numbers with a leading 0 by prepending the number string from folder name with `1` as explained by [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) is great and makes the code even easier and a little bit faster:

```
@echo off
goto GetFolderList

rem Run DIR to get a list of only folder names because of /AD and /B
rem matching the wildcard pattern ?? - ??-?? ordered reverse by name
rem because of /O-N with suppressing the error message DIR outputs if
rem no such folder can be found in current directory by redirecting
rem the error message to device NUL.

rem From folder name just the first two characters are assigned to loop
rem variable I as the default delimiters space/tab are used on splitting
rem up the folder name into tokens. Only the first token is processed by
rem outer FOR with the default options, i.e. the number to increment.

rem The inner FOR executes the SET command only if the first space/tab
rem delimited string of current folder name from DIR output contains any
rem non digit character. So if environment variable Number is defined
rem after inner FOR loop execution, the folder name is not valid as it
rem does not start with a number with 2 digits.

rem On current folder name not starting with a number, the outer FOR loop
rem is processed further with next folder name. Otherwise the number of
rem the current folder name being automatically the highest number because
rem of using leading zeros and reverse output by name is assigned to the
rem environment variable Number and outer FOR loop is exited with a jump
rem to label IncrementNumber.

rem The numbering for first folder starts with 01 in case of no (valid)
rem folder matching wildcard pattern ?? - ??-?? is found in current folder.

:GetFolderList
set "Number="
for /F %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N "?? - ??-??" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "delims=0123456789" %%J in ("%%I") do set "Number=none"
    if defined Number (
        set "Number="
    ) else (
        set Number=%%I
        goto IncrementNumber
    )
)
set "Number=01"
goto CreateFolder


rem On incrementing a number with leading zeros using an arithmetic expression
rem it can happen easily that the number is interpreted octal, especially if
rem the number would have 3 digits which is not the case here. That can be
rem avoided here by changing the strings "00" to "99" to "100" to "199".

rem Next it is safe to increment the number by 1. Then it is necessary to get
rem from number in range 101 to 200 the last 2 characters from number string.

:IncrementNumber
set "Number=1%Number%"
set /A Number+=1
set "Number=%Number:~-2%"
goto CreateFolder


rem The WMIC command below with used options outputs among blank
rem lines in UTF-16 Little Endian encoding also a line with

rem LocalDateTime=20170617192138.218000+120

rem Of interest from this line is the string after the equal sign as it
rem contains year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond and UTC
rem offset of configured time zone in fixed and region independent format.

rem From this date/time string just the month and day is needed for the
rem folder name in format DD-MM with incremented number being prepended.

:CreateFolder
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDateTime=%%I"
set "FolderName=%Number% - %LocalDateTime:~6,2%-%LocalDateTime:~4,2%"
md "%FolderName%"
```

**One more note:**

A command line like

```
set "FolderName=%LocalDateTime:~0,4%-%LocalDateTime:~4,2%-%LocalDateTime:~6,2%
```

after the **FOR** command line with **WMIC** command would define the folder name in format `YYYY-MM-DD` which is most often used in folder and file names because with this international date format the files and folders sorted by name are automatically also sorted by date.

So when there is no need to create multiple folders on same day which really requires in folder name an incrementing number, it would be much better to use the international date format in folder name and the batch code can be reduced to:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDateTime=%%I"
md "%LocalDateTime:~0,4%-%LocalDateTime:~4,2%-%LocalDateTime:~6,2%
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret charcter `^` to be interpreted as literal character by Windows command interpreter on parsing entire **FOR** command line and later on execution of **WMIC** command line by FOR as redirection operator.